# HTML Table & Image Problems - Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm having problems with viewing a table in Firefox, and wondered if anyone would be able to help? Here's how my page appears in Firefox:

http://s15.postimg.org/sx6cn6ktn/Problem_Firefox.jpg

But looks fine in Internet Explorer:

http://s16.postimg.org/e96xsuwj9/Problem_IE.jpg

My HTML coding is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE_HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">  
<title>Website Name | Album Name</title>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="logo"><img height="182.135433071px"; width="276.699212598px"; src="ctlogonew.jpg"></img> </div>
<div id="header"><img height="182.135433071px"; width="700px"; src="header1.png"</img>   </div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Album Name">Album</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
   <hr>
    <!---HEADER ENDS HERE--->


    <h1>Welcome to Website</h1>
    <table border="1px" width="100%">
<col width="40">
<col width="60">
<tr>
    <td><img width="400px" src="homepic.jpg"></img></td>
    <td><p>Welcome to xxxxx - an indie-rock band from Norwich.</p><p> The band are known in the industry for creating great music, with all members, including xxxxxxxxxx having a passion for the genre. Formed in 2010, and based in Norwich, Norfolk, the band have increased massively in popularity since then, selling out all performances for their tour in 2012, with more scheduled for 2013, as well as developing a following in London and on the festival scene.</p><p>The band are known musically for their own brand of indie pop music, containing riffs, hooks and soaring choruses, which has seen them become an online sensation worldwide</p><p>Explore our website for our latest news, details of our latest album <strong><i>Album Name</strong></i>, and purchase merchandise from the store.</p><p> Fans can also explore our Facebook and Twitter profiles, and get in touch with us via the Contact Us page. </p></td>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS coding is below:

```
#wrap {
width:1000px;
height:1000px;
background-color:black;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo {
width:276.699212598px;
height:182.135433071px;
background-color:black;
align:left;
float:left;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
#header {
width:700px;
height:182.135433071px;
background-color:white;
float:right;
}
ul{
line-height:90px;
list-style-type:none;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
}
li{
display:inline;
}
a:link,a:visited {
font-family:Reprise Title, Gill Sans MT, Trebuchet MS, Sans-serif;
font-size:2em;
font-weight:bold;
border-radius:5px;
color:#000000;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
padding:6px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active {
background-color:#7A991A;
}


  {
  border:1px solid #0000ff;
}
div.desc {
text-align:center;
font-weight:normal;
width:120px;
 margin:2px;
}
hr {
height:4px;
background-color:white;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:30px;
}
/*HEADER ENDS HERE*/
h1 {
font-family:Reprise Title, Gill Sans MT, Trebuchet MS, Sans-serif;
font-size:2em;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-weight:bold;
margin-left:20px;
}
p {
font-family: Gill Sans MT, Trebuchet MS, Sans-Serif;
font-size: 1em;
color: #FFFFFF;
}


table {
font-family: Gill Sans MT, Sans-Serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 3px;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Many thanks.

Comment: Your link to the `Problem_IE` page actually points to `Problem_Firefox.jpg`.

Comment: Your doctype is wrong, which might be knocking both browsers into "quirks mode" (essentially an IE5 compatibility mode) which causes all sorts of craziness. The underscore should be a space, i.e. `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: You do not have a closing `</head>` tag before starting your `<body>`.

Comment: `col width` is obsolete in HTML5; you should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unit to the values in colgroup. Seems to work for me with your code.

col width="40%"

col width="60%"

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

- As was said in the comments, your DOCTYPE is misspelled, throwing the document into Quirks mode. And different browsers have different quirks, so if you're after browser interoperability, don't use it.
- These days it's good practice to write tag names in lowercase, so `<html>` rather than `<HTML>`. But of course you can write them however you want; just be consistent.
- The `</head>` end tag is missing, but that too is not an error. It's just not recommended these days; I mean, all omitting that tag does is save 8 or 9 bytes.
- You have errors in your width and height attributes of the images. Those should only contain whole numbers. Besides, who ever heard of an image of 182.13 pixels high?
- Those semicolons in the img tags are bad. Get rid of them.
- The second img is also missing a `>`.
- There is no such thing as an `</img>` end tag.
- Your imgs don't have alt attributes.
- Your comment has an odd number of dashes. Straighten those out.
- In the table, the width attribute is off again. And really, you ought to read up on your CSS. All those width and height attributes don't serve a purpose nowadays.
- End tags for `<i>` and `<strong>` are the wrong way round. Besides, you meant `<cite>`, not `<i>` and `<strong>`.
- Missing `</table>` end tag.

The CSS:

- `align` is not a style property.
- You don't clear your floats. Make it a habit to always clear your floats.
- It's a good idea to always put quotes around font family names, especially if they contain spaces.
- There is one style rule without a selector.

If you correct all these errors, chances are your website will look much more similar across browsers.